# How to build a binary classifier/predictor for 1-d vector data in Python

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, prediction

**[Disclaimer]** This is my first excursion into machine learning.

I have a list of 1-d numpy real vectors that represent experimental conditions known to be associated to two mutually exclusive classes. To each vector a 1 or 0 can be assigned as the class label.

What is the best way to construct a classifier/predictor using these classes in Python such that the differences between the two classes are maximized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 1000 vectors with 10 values. Your x data has shape (1000,10), y data (1000,1) (it's either 0 or 1, according to class). You want to predict y from x.

The simplest model could look like (using Keras):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

mdl = Sequential()     // create model

mdl.add(Dense(8, input_shape=(10,), activation='sigmoid'))
mdl.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

mdl.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

mdl.fit(x, y, epochs = 30)
```

Note that I can use sigmoid in the last layer of classification problem only if there are  2 classes. With more  classes you should use softmax.

I recommend you check this page: https://keras.io/

Also, I think keras is better to begin with than tensorflow.